# How can i use table row id as parameter for angularjs function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get the value of data-id attribute and pass it as parameter for showData() function?

```html
<tr ng-repeat="schedule in schedules" ng-model="schedID" data-id="{{schedules.indexOf(schedule)}}">
  <td>MON-THU</td>
  <td>ACTIVITY CENTER</td>
  <td>National Service Training Program 2 (MERGED)</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" ng-click="showData()">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you show controller code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $index instead:

```
<tr ng-repeat="schedule in schedules" ng-model="schedID" data-id="{{schedules.indexOf(schedule)}}">
  <td>MON-THU</td>
  <td>ACTIVITY CENTER</td>
  <td>National Service Training Program 2 (MERGED)</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" ng-click="showData(schedules.indexOf(schedule))">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the value of $index change when I filter the content of the table. Using the indexOf the values are remain unchanged but my problem is how can I pass it to showData() function as parameter.

Comment: The index will always change when the data changes. Why not just pass the object itself?

Comment: Did you use the object instead? Why was my answer accepted all of a sudden?

Comment: I used this "showData(schedules.indexOf(schedule))" to pass the schedule index as parameter for showData. Thanks for your answer.